# How to retrieve an entity using a property from datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, persistentmanager

Is it possible to retrieve an entity from gae datastore using a property and not using the key?

I could see I can retrieve entities with key using the below syntax.

```
quote = mgr.getObjectById(Students.class, id);
```

Is there an alternative that enables us to use a property instead of key?
Or please suggest any other ways to achieve the requirement.

Thanks,
Karthick.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible. Think of the key of an entity being like the primary key of an SQL row (but please, don't stretch the analogy too far - the point is it's a primary key - the implementations of these two data storage systems are very different and it causes people trouble when they don't keep this in mind).

You should look either [here (JDO)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries) to read about JDO queries or [here (JPA)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html) to read about JPA queries, depending what kind of `mgr` your post refers to. For JDO, you would do something like this:

```
// begin building a new query on the Cat-kind entities (given a properly annotated
// entity model class "Cat" somewhere in your code)
Query q = pm.newQuery(Cat.class);

// set filter on species property to == param
q.setFilter("species == speciesParam"); 

// set ordering for query results by age property descending
q.setOrdering("age desc"); 

// declare the parameters for this query (format is "<Type> <name>") 
// as referenced above in filter statement
q.declareParameters("String speciesParam");

// run the query 
List<Cat> results = (List<Cat>) q.execute ("siamese");
```

For JPA, you would use JPQL strings to run your queries.